# how long is xhost +local: active

Tags: x11, xhost

Could someone tell me if the following command is permanent?

```
xhost +local:
```

or is it reset after I close the application, session or reboot?

or do I need to run afterwards the following command to undo the one above?

```
xhost -
```

Answer (score 5):

This is definitively not permanent and belongs to the affected X server. If this X server is restarted this setting is lost.

If you want to remove this setting, restart X server or use your command above:

```
xhost -localhost
```

(or `xhost -` to remove all access rights)